# "You are spoilt" or "You are spoiled"

Tags: adjectives, british-english

When helping my son with the homework in (non-native) English, I got stuck by  sentence.

What is correct: "You are spoilt!" or "You are spoiled!" or both alternatives?

---

- If it matters, this part of the book treats British English
- I do not wish to influence any answer, hence I keep my thoughts and the text for my self (for now)

---

Comment: Both are acceptable. *Spoilt* is an older form, less frequently used nowadays.

Comment: Look up 'spoil' in a decent online dictionary and see what the allowable form/s past participle is/are.

Comment: @WS2 Thank you, I guess I stick to the one I am used to. Also, judging from your comment, I guess  this is not a geographical issue.

Comment: The [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=spoilt%2Cspoiled&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cspoilt%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cspoiled%3B%2Cc0) of **spoiled** and **spoilt** is interesting, suggesting that **spoilt** - always the less-preferred word - enjoyed currency in the late 19th and early 20th centuries.  I'm not altogether sure what to make of this, but suspect that there may be geographic and sociological factors at work.

Comment: Who knows, maybe there is a distinction.   If that kid is a real brat, I may say he is spoiled, but if the milk has turned sour I may say it is spoilt.  Try to find *that* with Ngram....

Comment: I don't think I've ever actually heard anyone say "spoilt" in the US.  I believe that Mark Twain may have used it when writing dialect, but that's about as close as it gets.

Comment: @GEdgar: **Children** can be spoilt, but **food** is spoiled. [See Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=spoilt+children%2C+spoiled+children%2C+spoilt+meat%2C+spoiled+meat%2C+spoilt+food%2C+spoiled+food&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cspoilt%20children%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cspoiled%20children%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cspoilt%20meat%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cspoiled%20meat%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cspoilt%20food%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cspoiled%20food%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: As I wrote in the post, I did not like to share my thoughts. However, now that seems fine: The school grammar book, used for 10 yearish children, uses *spoilt* and they are not mentioning *spoiled* at all.

Answer (score 1):

Irregular past tenses ending in -t have become less popular over the years, and are consistently less popular than their -ed forms. The only international English exception I can find being "knelt", though in BrEng,"leapt" has gained currency in recent times, and "burnt" has only very recently fallen out of favor.

[Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=spoilt%2Cspoiled%2Cleaped%2Cleapt%2Cburned%2Cburnt%2Cspilled%2Cspilt%2Cdreamed%2Cdreamt%2Clearned%2Clearnt%2Cspelled%2Cspelt&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cspoilt%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cspoiled%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cleaped%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cleapt%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cburned%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cburnt%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cspilled%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cspilt%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdreamed%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdreamt%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clearned%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clearnt%3B%2Cc0)

[image]

The following [chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=spoilt%20child%2C%20spoiled%20child&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cspoilt%20child%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cspoiled%20child%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cspoilt%20child%3B%2Cc1%3B.t1%3B%2Cspoiled%20child%3B%2Cc1) demonstrates the marginal difference between *spoilt child* and *spoiled child* in recent years.

[image]

Comment: How about *sweep, swept; creep, crept; weep, wept; sleep, slept; mean, meant; feel, felt*?

Comment: So what's your actual answer to the question? Spoilt, spoiled, or either? Looks like either, but you don't say, I'm just interpreting.

Comment: Converted to community wiki, since edits significantly improved the answer.